# Flutter One Signal Do Some Action When Notification Pop-up Has Clicked

Tags: flutter, push-notification, navigation, onesignal

We have an application that works with One Signal mobile notifications service. The applications main page's structure is PageView with 4 inner pages. Our plan is that when user click notification pop up, the app opens with PageView's last indexed page like **page_index = 3**. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried solutions in that link:
[How do I open a specific page on onesignal notification click on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953985/how-do-i-open-a-specific-page-on-onesignal-notification-click-on-flutter)

I have changed page navigation to **page_index = 3** but that didn't work.